# Matching pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, grep, pattern-matching, subprocess

I had a directory "/pcap_test" which contains several log files. Each file has a pattern like:

> Pkt: 1 (358 bytes), LIFE: 1, App: itunes (INTO), State: TERMINATED, Stack: /ETH/IP/UDP/itunes, Error: None
>
> Pkt: 2 (69 bytes), LIFE: 2, App: zynga (INTO), State: INSPECTING, Stack: /ETH/IP/UDP, Error:     None
>
> Pkt: 3 (149 bytes), LIFE: 2, App: pizzeria (INTO), State: TERMINATED, Stack: /ETH/IP/UDP/pizzeria, Error: None

In this case I want the output to be the second line because the content in the "App" is not present in the "Stack: "

I wrote a small Python script to iterate through the directory, open each file and print the 
output:

```
import os
list = os.listdir("/home/test/Downloads/pcap_test")
print list
for infile in list:
  infile = os.path.join("/home/test/Downloads/pcap_test" , infile)

if os.path.isfile(infile):
str = file(infile, 'r').read()
print str
```

I somehow got the output using grep but unable to use the same in the python script. Its something like:

```
grep -vP 'App: ([^, ]*) \(INTO\).*Stack: .*\1.*$' xyz.pcap.log | grep -P 'App: ([^, ]*) \(INTO\)'
```

Since I already have the file named "str" , I want to use that rather than individual log files, to get the output.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd advise against variable names like `str` as that's Python's name for the `String` primitive data type.

Since grep is a command-line regular expression tool and since you already have a working regular expression all you need to do is learn to use Python's [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

What's a little difficult is capturing grep's `-v` behaviour. I suggest reading the file line by line and printing the line only if it does not match your first regular expression but does match the second, like so:

```
if os.path.isfile(infile):
    with file(infile, 'r') as logFile: #this will close the file pointer automatically when you finish
        for line in logFile: #read logFile one line at a time
            firstReMatch = re.match(r'App: ([^, ]*) \(INTO\).*Stack: .*\1.*$', line) #check if this line matches your first regex
            secondReMatch = re.match(r'App: ([^, ]*) \(INTO\)', line) #check if this line matched your second regex
            if secondReMatch and not firstReMatch: #"not" to capture the inverse match
                print line #print the line.
```

Depending on your data, you may want to [use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: the expression : 

firstReMatch = re.match('App: ([^, ]*) \(INTO\).*Stack: .*\1.*$', line)

wont work in python the way it works in grep. There are some spaces which needs to be taken care of using regex in python (/s). As you pointed out , I was trying to get the same output using puthon;s re.findall() but couldn't come to any solution as got confused. Using grep might need subprocess calls but I think using regix can solve this issue. Just couldn't hit the nail on its head.

Comment: @learning I don't understand. You can't convert the code in my answer into what you want? Incidentally, I realized that I wasn't using raw strings (`r"this is a raw string with the r in front"`). I've updated my answer.

Comment: I got that working using re.findall. Thanks for the help acattle.